# SharePoint REST API Post date from Input value

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-addin, rest

I am currently developing a SharePoint 2013 app and I have ran into an issue.

I have REST api that runs when the user tries to submit data, I have managed to get the Title field to submit the SharePoint list but I cannot get the Date Input value to submit to the list. The list is situated in the Host Web and the rest of the code does appear to work.

I am seeing a '400 (bad request)' in the console when submitting.

I currently have the following code:

```
function Submit() {
$('#submitBtn').click(function () {
    var listName = "MyList";
    var itemType = "SP.List";

    var item = {
        "__metadata": { "type": itemType },
        "Title": $('#TitleInput').val(),
        "Date": $('#DateInput').val()
    };

    var url = appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)" +
        "/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?" +
        "@target='" + hostweburl + "'";

    var bodyItem = JSON.stringify(item);

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Item created in host web");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("Failed to add item to host web");
        }
    });
});
```

}

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have had a Google on how to do this but so far turned up no reliable results.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283106/beginner-javascript-date-conversion-from-string-to-utc-date-js-into-sharepoint

Answer (score 4):

You can use [ISO 8601](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/iso8601.htm) format (`YYYY-MM-DD`) for dates.  The following will work:

- `2015-08-11`
- `2015-08-11T12:40:16Z`

If you are in chrome, using a date input (`<input type="date" />`), then it will always [return it in ISO 8601 format](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/08/Quick-FAQs-on-input-type-date-in-Google-Chrome?hl=en).  If not, and you're using a JavaScript library to create a datepicker control, then check if they have a format options.  Otherwise use JavaScript to format the date as needed.  If you have a Date object, then calling `Date.toJSON()` will format the date correctly.

Comment: I currently have an input like this:
`<input type="date" name="Date" id="expensesDateInput" required/>`

I am also using Chrome however it does not seem to be submitting to the SharePoint list that we have, the title submits just fine but not the date.