# Add row to SharePoint List (People or group column multiple ID's) in Rest API

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-rest-api, error, person-or-group

I'm trying to add multiple people into a list column of the type People or Group that can have more than 1 person.

My Column ProjectOwner doesn't exist If I pick up the data in the rest API, but there are 2 columns (ProjectOwnerStringId and ProjectOwnerId). Whatever I try I get the error:

> "Internal error in microsoft_sharepoint. (ID: a043fdc8-ee96-4cb9-9f0c-2bf6ab6756c7) Internal error".

Any help would be welcome

data:

```
{
      ProjectOwnerId: 
[
         15,
         29
      ],
      SPO_OwnerId: 15,
      ProjectName: test3,
      ProjectStartDate: 2022-10-15T13:35:20.000000+00:00,
      ProjectEndDate: 2199-12-31T00:00:00.000000+00:00,
      Project_Template: Ireland,15953,
      ProjectCurrency: 0.0,
      ProjectLocation: Please enter the project location,
      ProjectCode_CDE: BC1234,
      ProjectTimezone: Europe/London,
      JobNumber: Please enter the Job Number,
      ProjectType: Data Center,
      GoToURL: Complete,
      B360_Status: Complete,
      ProjectOwnerStringId: 
[
         15,
         29
      ],
      SPO_OwnerStringId: 15
    }
  },
  request_headers: 
[
     
{
      name: accept,
      value: application/json;odata=verbose
    },
     
{
      name: Content-Type,
      value: pplication/json
    },
     
{
      name: If-Match,
      value: *
    },
     
{
      name: X-HTTP-Method,
      value: MERGE
    }
  ],
  Action name: Add row toSites list,
  Method: post
}
```

Comment: Hi @user16068355, did you try my suggestions below? Is it working for you?

Comment: Yes I tried, but keep getting errors like this:

400 Bad Request: {"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The property 'ProjectOwnerStringId' does not exist on type 'SP.Data.SitesListItem'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type."}}}

Comment: Do not use `ProjectOwnerStringId`. Use only `ProjectOwnerId`.

Answer (score 0):

As your `ProjectOwner` column is multiple selection person or group column, you have to pass the array of user IDs to `ProjectOwnerId` property like:

```
ProjectOwnerId: { 'results': [15, 29] }
```

**Reference**: [Update People picker column using REST API in Power Automate](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/289066/update-people-picker-column-using-rest-api-in-power-automate/289067#289067)

---

**Additional information**:

For single selection person of group field, you can directly pass the user ID like:

```
ProjectOwnerId: 15
```

Comment: Also, for text columns, you have to pass the string values (wrapped in quotes) like `"Please enter the project location"` and for date columns, check [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/152903/sharepoint-rest-api-post-date-from-input-value) and [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/239924/unable-to-post-to-date-column-with-rest).